# Dealing with "view vs copy" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

I'm trying to decode my dataframe through the following code:

```
 df = pd.read_sql_table('mytable',con) 


 for column in df.columns :
     for i in range(len(df[column])):
         if type(df[column][i]) == bytearray or type(df[column][i]) == bytes:
             df[column][i] = str(df[column][i], 'utf-8')
```

but I keep getting SettingWithCopy warnings no matter what I try

Anyone know how to deal with this warning ?

### UPDATE:

I've end up settling for this:

```
if df[column].dtype == 'object':
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(x, bytes) else x)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to improve this:

1. It looks like you are converting the whole column to string so you don't need to loop through each value of the column.
2. You can use the inbuilt `pd.Series.astype()` method which is more efficient than `str()` as it is vectorized (i.e. you can call it on the whole Series).
3. Use `.loc` to avoid the setting with copy warning.

So your code will look like:

```py
 for column in df.columns :
    df.loc[column, :] = df[column].astype(str)
```

Note that `str` type will be encoded as `utf-8` in all but very old versions of Python. However if you are using 2.x you can do `df[column].astype('unicode')`.

Comment: You definitely put me in the right track, it helped a lot thanks!